# Can't put hyperlink in PHP echo statement

Tags: php

In the code below I'm adding `<a href=\"member.php\"></a>` in the echo statement.  But, I'm getting a syntax error when I add any hyperlink in my PHP.  Is there something I'm missing here?  Thank you.

```
if ($username==$dbusername && $password==$dbpassword)
                {
                    echo "You're in!  <a href=\"member.php\"><!--I'm getting the sytax error in the hyper link here.-->Click here</a> to enter the member area";
                    }

                    else                
                        echo "Incorrect username/password";
                        }

                        else
                            die('That user does not exist');
                            }

    else
        die('Please enter a username/password');

    ?>
```

**UPDATE**

Updated with escape tags.

Comment: escape the " around member.php - `echo "blah <a href=\"member.php\" .."`

Comment: The two `else`s will obviously fail.

Comment: lol, there's more to the code

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape your quotes:

```
echo "You're in! <a href=\"member.php\">Hello!</a>";
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're using double quotes for both **strings introduction** and for **HTML attributes**. You can't mix them and expect them to work properly.

You have two options - escape the double quotes inside string:

```
echo "You're in!  <a href=\"member.php\">Click here</a> to enter the member area";
```

Or use single quotes around the string:

```
echo 'You\'re in!  <a href="member.php">Click here</a> to enter the member area';
```

More about [strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: The second suggestion creates a problem with the apostrophe in `You're`.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "You're in!  <a href=\"member.php\">Click here</a> to enter the member area";
```