# Can't click on php links

Tags: php, html

I looked through at least 10 questions before I got here and then looked at every relevant question the site gave me with my question title.  The most relevant thing I found was:

[Can't put hyperlink in PHP echo statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046549/cant-put-hyperlink-in-php-echo-statement)

However, if I use either single or double quotes I still can't click any of the links.

```
    echo '<div a href="http://www.amouramis.com">yo</div>';
echo "<div a href='http://www.amouramis.com'>yo</div>";
```

I opened up the "view page source" and can click in there and it navigates, but it's all text in there, which defeats the purpose.

Maybe I messed up something earlier?  Here's the entire code (yes, it's crazy looking):

```
<?php

include "errorcontrol.php";
include "style.css";
$days=0;
ob_end_flush();
ob_start();
 do{
echo $days++;
$ten = ob_get_contents(); //10
$first = str_split($ten);
}while ($days<10);

ob_end_flush();
echo "<br>";
echo 10 + $days;
echo "<br>";

ob_start();
//20
do{
echo $days++;
$tenplus = ob_get_contents();
$second = str_split($tenplus, 2);
}
while ($days<32);
ob_end_flush();

//truncate
$all = array_merge((array)$first, (array)$second);//30


echo "<br>";
echo $ten;
echo "<br>" . "NEXT" . "<br>";
echo $tenplus;
echo "<br>" . "first array contents follow" . "<br>";
print_r($first);
echo "<br>" . "second array contents follow" . "<br>";
print_r($second);//40
echo "<br>";
echo "code ran";
echo "<br>";
print_r ($all);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$i="1";
echo $i;
echo "<br>";//50

$name = "name of table";



echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo '<th class="month">' . $name . '</th>';
echo "</tr>";
//60
do{
echo '<tr>' . '<td a href="http://www.hotmail.com/' . $i . '.html" class="border">' . $all[$i] . '</td>' . '</tr>';
$i++;
}while ($i < 32);

echo "</table>";

echo '<div a href="http://www.amouramis.com">yo</div>';
echo "<div a href='http://www.amouramis.com'>yo</div>";
?>
```

Comment: Please consider indenting your code, and perhaps even writing in some helpful comments. It would make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PHP.  You can't click on these links because these aren't links:

```
<div a href="http://www.amouramis.com">yo</div>
```

What you have there is invalid HTML.  And a browser's behavior with invalid HTML is undefined.  A link would look like this:

```
<a href="http://www.amouramis.com">yo</a>
```

Or, within a `div`:

```
<div><a href="http://www.amouramis.com">yo</a></div>
```

Comment: Sorry.  Thanks, I did that and it worked right away.  Been doing html for a while.  Dunno how I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't valid HTML:

```
echo '<div a href="http://www.amouramis.com">yo</div>';
echo "<div a href='http://www.amouramis.com'>yo</div>";
```

If you want the whole div to be a link use:

```
echo '<a href="http://www.amouramis.com"><div>yo</div></a>';
```

If you want the text to be a link use:

```
echo '<div><a href="http://www.amouramis.com">yo</a></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Links are of the form `<a href="http://example.com/">Click here</a>`, without the `div` after the `<`.